# Bad Magic Number On Compile

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working compiling python into pyc files. I am using the command

```
python -m compileall .
```

Which is compiling all the files in the directory. But when I try to run the application

```
python3 main.pyc
```

It always throws the Bad Magic Number error. I've deleted the pyc files several times with:

```
find . -name "*.pyc" -delete
```

And recompiled about 10 times already. Still the same error. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: You are compiling with ``python``, but running with ``python3``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are compiling with `python`

But you are running with `python3`.

I suspect your `python` is actually python2 - hence the error (it happens when there is a version mismatch between the compiler and the executing python binary)
Try compiling with `python3`

```
python3 -m compileall .
```

Comment: Haaaaaa. I feel like "well no duh Sherlock" kinda mistake.